# change the height of ui.bootstrap.alert

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to add ui.bootstrap.alert based on this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview.

It works okay as following except that it's too big for me.
[image]

So I changed the height in CSS and here's the new output

```
.alert {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

[image]
But now the sentance is not in the middle of the alert anymore.

How can I properly change the height of the alert? Thanks!

Comment: Change `line-height` to 30 as well.

Comment: plunker link is no good

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You will need to change `line-height` and `padding` for this to work

```
.alert {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height:30px;
  padding:0px 15px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/kkGoNO

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<p class="alert-text">Esto es un mensaje de alerta</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .alert-text{
    margin-top: -0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what this is doing and which parts are important, code only answer are of low quality